# How do I ensure crontab commands run once on AWS when there may be multiple instances?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django project running on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.  It can have between 1 and 6 instances running.

I load a `crontab` file to run some `management/commands` overnight.  I have this `config` file:

```
container_commands:
  01_cron_job:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/crontab.txt /etc/cron.d/my_cron_jobs && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/my_cron_jobs"
    #leader_only: true
```

The file copied across looks like:

```
# Set the cron to run with utf8 encoding
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
   
# Specify where to send email 
MAILTO="me@gmail.com"

1 0 * * * root source /opt/python/current/env && nice /opt/python/current/app/src/manage.py clearsessions
15 0 * * * root source /opt/python/current/env && nice /opt/python/current/app/src/manage.py update_summary_stats >> /opt/python/log/update_summary_stats.log 2>&1
# this file needs a blank space as the last line otherwise it will fail
```

Within the `config` file, if I set `leader_only` to false then the command doesn't run if the leader instance gets deleted at some point (for example because another instance was added during peak times and the leader deleted when it quietened).  If I set `leader_only` to true then the crontab commands run on every instance.

What is the best way to set up `crontab` on AWS Elastic Beanstalk to only run once irrespective of the number of instances?   Thank you

Comment: If `leader_only` is `true` or `false` then it runs on all instances regardless?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry - corrected text

Comment: I see. Must the cron job run on one of the instances? What about making a dedicated instance (or lambda) for that which runs independently form your primary 6 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a lock file (perhaps locally on a shared [EFS mount](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/), or externally using a service such as [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) with [Transactional Consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/) or [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)).

When your application creates this lock file it could then continue as normal, however should the file exist you would skip the script.

By doing this it reduces the chance of a collision, however I would also recommend adding some jitter to the start of the script (add a sleep for a random amount of seconds) to reduce the chance further that the scripts will attempt to create this lockfile at the same time.

Comment: This is how I was thinking of doing it - I just wanted to check there wasn't something in the AWS setup that sorted it